# How to move a post to different post type with all meta data?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, customization

I'm trying to move a post from a custom post type called 'new cars' to 'sold cars' using the Post Type Switcher plugin, and the plugin works well, but the all meta data associated with this post still belonging to 'new cars' post type...

So, the problem appears when I list categories from 'new cars' post type and that 'sold car' make, model, colour and other metas still there...

Someone have an advice ?

Comment: Why don't you use categories for this?? one for sold and one for new...

Comment: The [Post Type Switcher Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-type-switcher/) just builds an interface around the [`set_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_type) function. This function changes the post type an entry in the `wp_posts` table. It does not change the post ID, nor does it touch the `wp_postmeta` table. Could you explain what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to list 'make' taxonomy but it show me booth sold cars and new cars....I want just new cars, It doesn't matter if if under separate category or post type, I just don't know how to list this things separately...

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned in the comments - changing the post type of a post only changes its 'post type' column. All post metadata is associated with the post ID and this never changes.

However, you may not *see* this information: if the old post type had a metabox or taxonomy associated with that, that the new post type doesn't - then while the relationship of the converted post with its metadata / taxonomies still exists in the database, it won't appear in the admin screen.

If you have any metaboxes or taxonomies for your 'new cars' post type, you'll want to register them with your 'sold cars' too. For taxonomies this is done by specifying the post types when registering:

```
register_taxonomy('my-taxonomy',array('new_cars','sold_cars', $args);
```

Or when registering a custom post_type (see [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)), or by using [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type).

Similarly you'll want to add your metaboxes to both post types:

```
add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, 'new_cars', $context, $priority, $callback_args )
add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, 'sold_cars', $context, $priority, $callback_args )
```

and ensure that the associated processing runs for both post types.

---

However - from what it seems you're after, you should be using a post type 'cars' and register a taxonomy (say 'car_status'), as well as you're existing 'make' taxonomy.

Then a car can be associated to a car status term (say 'new' or 'sold').

To get all *new* cars of make *xyz* you can use the `tax_query` argument of [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'car_status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'new')
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'make',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'xyz')
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args )
```

Comment: Stephen Harris, your explication was awesome!!
I've registered that taxonomy, like you said, and added the metaboxes, but ... I didn't understand that query... 

I tried to list all makes under 'car_status' new, but I got only the permalink...

Comment: @Santoro - if you are using the second approach you don't need to re-add the metaboxes etc - there is only one post type, but with two taxonomies. My advice is to ignore the first part, and register a 'car_status' taxonomy for your custom post type. Then for each car give it the term 'new' or 'sold'. Each car (post type) should have a 'make' term and 'car_status' term.

Comment: thanks for you quick answer... Sorry, but I dont know what function ise to list my makes taxonomy using car_status as conditional...should I use get_terms_by ?

Comment: Ok! I found a way to list my taxonomy terms, but...because its looping inside used cars, there are several used cars under 'BMW' make, and it shows me all of that...like 

    BMW
    BMW
    BMW
    MERCEDES
    MERCEDES
    JAGUAR

There is a way to display only one of these ?